# If a certain letter is included in a string then its coordinate will increase or decrease

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, input

The program should ask what its first coordinates are. Then movement is asked and its answer should be with

```
r,R,l,L,u,U,d,D.
```

Coordinate are input with a comma (x,y), and then again if 'u','d','l','r' are input then the x or y axis will increase or decrease.
'u' and 'd' for the y-axis; 'r' and 'l' for the x-axis.

```
def program_for_grid(x,y,where):
    if where == 'r' or where == 'R':
        # move x upp +
        for r in range(len(where)):
            r == 'r' or r == 'R'
            x + 1
    elif where == 'l' or where == 'L':
        # move x down -
        for l in range(len(where)):
            l == 'l' or l == 'L'
            x - 1
    elif where == 'u' or where == 'U':
        # move y up +
        for u in range(len(where)):
            u == 'u' or u == 'U'
            y + 1
    elif where == 'd' or where == 'D':
        # move y down -
        for d in range(len(where)):
            d == 'd' or d == 'D'
            y - 1

x_axis,y_axis = input('Initial position: ').split(',')
int_x_axix = int(x_axis)
int_y_axix = int(x_axis)

movement = input('Movement: ')

grid = program_for_grid(int_x_axix,int_y_axix,movement)
print(grid)
```

Comment: Make your life easier: convert the input to lowercase, then you only have to compare with one letter instead of two.

Comment: You're missing `if` before `r == 'r' or r == 'R'` and all the other similar lines.

Comment: The loop logic seems wacky too. You want to traverse the string once, and examine the current letter one at a time.

Comment: `x + 1` should be `x += 1`

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, what are you expecting `grid` to be set to?

Comment: Incrementing `x` and `y` in the function has no effect on the caller's variables. You need to return the new values and assign them back to the variables.

Comment: I got this now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def delta(movement):
    """
    Parse the string for movement instructions and
    return resulting relative coordinates
    """
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for letter in movement.lower():
        if letter == "d": y -= 1
        elif letter == "u": y += 1
        elif letter == "l": x -= 1
        elif letter == "r": x += 1
        else:
            print("warning: skipping undefined", letter)
    return x, y

x_axis,y_axis = input('Initial position: ').split(',')
int_x_axix = int(x_axis)
int_y_axix = int(y_axis)

while True:
    movement = input('Movement: ')
    xdelta, ydelta = delta(movement)
    int_x_axix += xdelta
    int_y_axix += ydelta
    print(f"resulting position: ({int_x_axix},{int_y_axix})")
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help! The program should also increase and decrease if the letter are in uppercase, I will just change that.

Comment: It already does that. The `delta` function creates a copy of the string with `.lower()` so that you don't have to compare against upper case separately, as suggested in Barmar's very first comment.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't see that :)

Comment: Something is off here:                                                                                             Initial position: 13,27       
Movement: udlrUDRL      
resulting position: (13,13) , try using udlrUDRL  as movement, it's resulting position should be (13,27)

Comment: Oh, there was a copy/paste error from your code; fixed now.